# Eclipse saying the html5 body attribute "ononline" is undefined

Tags: javascript, eclipse, html, browser, wifi

In my HTML5 web app I update the online status by using body attributes "ononline" and "onoffline" so each time the network is available I change the status by calling a function "updateIndicator()" (I found the code snippet somewhere in the web and it works partially), but Eclipse Kepler says these both attributes are undefined. Why is it so? Here my code snippets:

```
<body onload="updateIndicator()" ononline="updateIndicator()" onoffline="updateIndicator()">
    <div data-role="page" id="startscreen">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            DISPO   [ C:DisConnected,EventReset, M:x, R:<span id="indicator">(state unknown)</span>, G:<span id="GPSIndicator">(state unknown)</span> ]
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here the function:

```
function updateIndicator(){
document.getElementById('indicator').innerHTML = navigator.onLine ? 'OK' : 'X';
document.getElementById('GPSIndicator').textContent = navigator.geolocation ? 'OK' : 'X';}
```

After the page is loaded and I am online both "R" and "G" show "OK", but after I switch WLAN off nothing happens although I suppose "R" and "G" should show "X". Am I doing something wrong? Or doesn't the browser recognize the WLAN is switched off? If so, how should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

> Eclipse Kepler says these both attributes are undefined. Why is it so?

Most likely because Eclipse Kepler is trying to validate HTML4 or XHTML, does it matter?

> Am I doing something wrong?

Other than not following the principles of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), no.

> Or doesn't the browser recognize the WLAN is switched off?

It might, but not having any WLAN is not the same as not having any network connectivity, and having WLAN does not necessarily mean you can connect to whatever server might be important for the app.

> If so, how should I achieve that?

Send a request to the server and see whether it works or not.  You'll probably find [the answer to 'HTML5 / JS - check that application is offline'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786599/8655) useful as well as the blog post ['Broken Offline Support'](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/19/broken-offline-support/).